# I am not able to compare my second password with my first password. Who can give me the solution

Tags: assembly, x86-16

```
.model

.stack

.data

    fMenu DB 10,13,"************************************"
          DB 10,13,"*****   Welcome TO Our System  *****"
          DB 10,13,"*****  +---------------------+ *****"
          DB 10,13,"*****  |     1. Register     | *****"
          DB 10,13,"*****  |     2.  Login       | *****"
          DB 10,13,"*****  |     3.  Exit        | *****"
          DB 10,13,"*****  +---------------------+ *****"
          DB 10,13,"************************************"
          DB 10,13,"    Enter Your Selection : $"
    NUM1  DB ?
    LEN EQU ($-RPASS)
    ;MSG
    STR3 db 10,13,"Failed to register$"
    STR4 DB 10,13,"SUCCESS to REgister$"
    ;-----user login and register msg
    STR1  DB 10,13,10,13,"*****LOGIN PAGE*****$"
    STR2  DB 10,13,"*****REGISTER PAGE*****$"
    USER  DB 10,13,"USERNAME : $"
    PASS  DB 10,13,"PASSWORD : $"
    ;user input
    RUSER DB 13 DUP(?)
    RPASS DB 10 DUP(?)
    CPASS DB 10 DUP(?)
    LUSER DB 13 DUP(?)
    LPASS DB 10 DUP(?)
.code

main proc

    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

Start:

    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, fMenu
    int 21h
    
    mov ah,01h ;let user prompt 1 number
    int 21h
    mov NUM1,al
    
    mov NUM1,'1'
    JE REGISTER
    
REGISTER:

    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,STR2
    int 21h
    
    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,USER
    int 21h
    mov ah,3fh
    mov bx,0
    mov cx,13
    lea dx,RUSER
    int 21h
    CMP al,13
    JMP Dispass

DisPass:

    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,Pass
    int 21h
    mov si,0

setpass:
    
    MOV AH,08H
    INT 21H
    CMP AL,0DH
    JE Comfirm
    MOV [RPASS+SI],AL
    MOV DL,'*'
    MOV AH,02H
    INT 21H
    INC SI
    JMP setpass
Comfirm:
    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,Pass
    int 21h
DisC:
    MOV AH,08H
    INT 21H
    CMP AL,0DH
    JE compare
    MOV [CPASS+SI],AL
    MOV DL,'*'
    MOV AH,02H
    INT 21H
    INC SI
    jmp disc
    
    mov bx,0
    mov cx,0
compare:
    mov al,[CPASS+bx]
    cmp dl,[RPASS+bx]
    cmp al,dl
    jne FAIl
    inc bx
    loop compare
    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,str4
    int 21h
Fail:
    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,str3
    int 21h


exit:
 mov ah,4ch
 int 21h
main endp
end main
```

Comment: There's only code in the question, and no question. Add a description.

Comment: It's also an excessively *long* block of code.  Please reduce it to a [mcve] and explain in detail what is wrong with it.  How do you build and run it, what do you expect to have happen, what happens instead?  Without such improvements this question will probably be closed.

Comment: Instead of the second `mov NUM1,'1'` you should compare: `cmp al,'1'`. If the user choice is equal to `'1'`, you are doing `JE REGISTER`, but what when it is not `'1`?
Also revise the `loop compare`. When you have initialized loop counter with `mov cx,0`, the loop performs 65535 times, unless it is broken at whatever garbage follows both passwords. You should initialize `cx` with the password size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> mov NUM1,'1'
> JE REGISTER
> ```

The `mov` should become a `cmp` instruction.

> ```
> cmp dl,[RPASS+bx]
> cmp al,dl
> ```

The first `cmp` should become a `mov` instruction

> ```
>    mov cx,0
> compare:
> ```

As Vitsoft commented, the counter needs to be initialized with the length of the password, but you could use the value 10 also because that's the length of the input buffers.

Before your *DisC* loop begins you need to reset the `SI` register to zero. It still holds the last non-zero value from the previous loop. The confirmation password will get stored in the wrong memory buffer.

---

> ```
> LEN EQU ($-RPASS)
> ```

Although *LEN* is not used in this code snippet, because of the position of the *RPASS* label this will become a negative number! This will be your future error...